# Hibernate creates wrong table relations in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with Hibernate. I am using Spring 2.7.5. I have three entities.

- Alarm,
- AlarmList,
- ListAlarmJoinTable.

Alarm and AlarmList are in a MtoM relation. The tricky part is that they are not referencing each other, but they both have a OneToMany reference to the ListAlarmJoinTable.

Here are the classes:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "alarm")
public class Alarm {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer alarmId;

    @Column(unique = true)
    String name;
    private Long time;
    private Integer code;
    private Integer priority;
    private String source;
    private String description;
    private String codeAsAsString;
    private String priorityAsString;
    private Integer dmId;
    private Boolean internal;
    private Integer instnaceindex;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<ListAlarmJoinTable> alarmLists;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JsonAlarm [time=" + time + ", code=" + code + ", priority="
                + priority + ", source=" + source + ", description="
                + description + ", alarmId=" + alarmId + ", codeAsAsString="
                + codeAsAsString + ", priorityAsString=" + priorityAsString
                + ", dmId=" + dmId + ", internal=" + internal
                + ", instnaceindex=" + instnaceindex + "]";
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Table(name = "alarm_list")
public class AlarmList {

    @Id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<ListSequenceJoinTable> alarmSequences;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<ListAlarmJoinTable> alarms;

}
```

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "list_alarms_join_table")
public class ListAlarmJoinTable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AlarmListId id;
    private int position;

}
```

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AlarmListId implements Serializable {

    private Integer alarmId;
    private String listId;

}
```

When Hibernate creates the schema and tables, it creates the following tables:

"alarm", "alarm_list", "alarm_alarm_lists" , "alarm_list_alarms", "list_alarms_join_table".

What I actually need are these: "alarm", "alarm_list", "list_alarms_join_table".
Now, at first I thought it was the dialect, so I tried out every MySQL dialect and it didn't work. I even ran `maven clean install` (even though I knew that wouldn't change anything).

For further information this is my application.properties:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjmxB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping is wrong because JPA cannot guess that `ListAlarmJoinTable` is essentially a join table (with an extra property). JPA sees your setup and thinks the relations `Alarm` → `AlarmListId` and `AlarmList` → `AlarmListId` have nothing to do with the fields of the `AlarmListId`, that you intended to be foreign keys.

Change the `AlarmListId` as follows to make the relation explicit:

```java
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AlarmListId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=LAZY)
    private Alarm alarm;
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=LAZY)
    private AlarmList list;

    // You MUST implement hashCode() and equals(), probably Lombok's
    // @EqualsAndHashCode is enough but please check the semantics!!!
}
```

Now, you have to use `mappedBy` in the `@OneToMany` annotations over `Alarm.alarmLists` and `AlarmList.alarms`. I *think* the value should be:

```java
    @OneToMany(..., mappedBy = "id.alarm")
    private List<ListAlarmJoinTable> alarmLists;

    // AND:

    @OneToMany(..., mappedBy = "id.list")
    private List<ListAlarmJoinTable> alarms;
```

The `mappedBy` property will help JPA understand that these are just the reverse sides of the *same* relation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, ill give it a try and notify you